# Unable to assign values to an html input tag

Tags: javascript

I want to put values in an html input tag in a html page that have this code:

```
<input name="mifa" type="text" value="undefined" maxlength="5" max="99999" class="mifInput">
```

If, in the html page, I manually put numbers, it goes OK. If I manually put letters, it just disapears and the input becames empty again.

I tried the next code. It turns a string (moa4) into a number (moa5 - typeof confirms its a number). I want to put moa5 in the input box. I use this:

```
moa4 = moa3[0];
moa5=parseInt(moa4, 10);
document.getElementsByClassName("mifInput")[0].value = moa5;
```

The number is put (apears in the input box) but disapears at once. Like if I put letters manually.

I have tried this code after moa5 and before the last line, but didn't work:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("mifInput")[0].removeAttribute('onpaste');
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jcbhfd7k/ seems ok to me. Something else is happening which isn't part of the code you shared. Hard to know what that is without more info.

Comment: Any ideas where to look?

Comment: No, because I can't see your code. I have no idea what else is going on in your page or script.

Answer (score 0):

remove value ="undefined" and it works

```html
<input name="mifa" type="text"  maxlength="5" max="99999" class="mifInput">
```

Comment: @ADyson thank u for the addup.. out of curiosity when exactly does valeu='undefined' come in handy?

Comment: I don't know really, you can set anything as the default "value", although why anyone would set it to undefined I don't know, it doesn't really achieve anything.